# Installing OpenCV using Virtual Environment (Ubuntu 16)

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04, spyder, conda, virtual-environment

I want to install OpenCV. First thing I did was creating a virtual environment by following command in Ubuntu 16:

" conda create -n opencv3.4_py3.6 "

Then, I followed the official instruction here (Building OpenCV from source):

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

However, when I tried to install dependencies, the following message came up:

```
Unable to locate package "Package Name"
```

As it can be seen int the attached image

[image]

My purpose is installing OpenCV in a Virtual Environment. Also, I want to import and use OpenCV in **Spyder**.

Any idea about how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) After doing

`conda create -n opencv3.4_py3.6`

you need to run these other three commands to get what you want

`source activate opencv3.4_py3.6`

`conda install opencv python=3.6*`

`conda install spyder`

You don't need to compile Opencv because you can install it with conda.